# How to use roscpp TimerEvent API in class

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am very new to ROS and quite rusty on my C++.
Currently I'm on Fuerte and Ubuntu 12.04.
I was following the roscpp tutorial which explains how to create a simple publisher and subscriber.

I think I understand the tutorial fairly ok so I wanted to try and generalize it a little bit and instead of creating the nodes inside their respective main() as done in the tutorial to try and create classes for them.

I tried rewriting the publisher part first and came up with the following code (Based on the roscpp overview pages and my own ideas.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

class BasicNode
{
private:

public:
    BasicNode() {};
    void timerCallback(const ros::TimerEvent& event);
    
    //Utilities
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Timer timer;
    ros::Publisher pub;
    std_msgs::String str;
};

void BasicNode::timerCallback(const ros::TimerEvent& event) {
    str.data = "hello world";
    pub.publish(str);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    BasicNode MyPubNode;
    ros::init(argc, argv, "BasicNode");
    MyPubNode.pub = MyPubNode.nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter",1000);
    MyPubNode.timer = MyPubNode.nh.createTimer(ros::Duration(0.1), &MyPubNode.timerCallback, &MyPubNode);

}
```

I try and compile the file but get the following error:

```
/home/rikonor/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/beginner_tutorials/src/BasicNode.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/rikonor/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/beginner_tutorials/src/BasicNode.cpp:28:76: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&BasicNode::timerCallback’ [-fpermissive]
```

I tried a different approach as well changing the following:

```
MyPubNode.timer = MyPubNode.nh.createTimer(ros::Duration(0.1), BasicNode::timerCallback);
```

and received the following error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void BasicNode::timerCallback(const ros::TimerEvent&)’
```

If anybody can direct me to what I am doing wrong I will appreciate it.
Am I even going at it the right way? Is this the conventional way?
In the meantime I'll keep trying and figure it out, if I find anything, I'll post it back here.
Thank you,
rikonor

--------EDIT--------

Hi,

I think I found out what I did wrong, I did call ros::spin().
I edited the code to add the following:

```
while(ros::ok())
    {
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
```

or

```
ros::spin();
```

Is this indeed enough or am I missing anything else?
Also since I called ros::spin() inside of main(), would you recommend a class function that does it instead, and gets called from main? To be honest I don't see how it matters but I thought I'd ask.

Again, thank you.
rikonor

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54335/how-to-use-roscpp-timerevent-api-in-class/) by [rikonor](https://answers.ros.org/users/4137/rikonor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-05**:
I personally prefer to do spinning from the main, but the problem is unrelated as you had a problem at compile-time. Forgetting to spin will result in missing functionality at run-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The notation for member functions is `::`, not `.`. Use `&MyPubNode::timerCallback` instead of `&MyPubNode.timerCallback`.

Also it might be a good idea to do the initialization from the constructor instead of from the main.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1